# Turn ECC off in HP Proliant ML350 G4

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ecc

I have got an HP Proliant ML350 generation 4. I want to upgrade the memory but I only have non-ECC memory. How can i disable ECC in the bios settings to let the non-ECC ram work?

Comment: And what happens when you use your non-ECC ram?

Comment: I don't think you can turn-off ECC nor you can plug-in a non-ECC memory and expect it to work. I'd recommend you check compatible memory for the server and use them.

Answer (score 5):

From the [HP ProLiant ML350 Generation 4 Server Maintenance and Service Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc%2fdocs%2fsupport%2fsupportmanual%2fc00218063%2fc00218063.pdf), p48:

> Use only 256-MB, 512-MB, 1-GB, 72-bit wide, 2.5-B, PC2100 Registered
>   ECC DDR SDRAM. Use Compaq branded or HP DDR SDRAM only.

The second part about using branded memory is usually not important - compatible memory modules from any major memory manufacturer would probably be fine. The first part, on the other hand, is significant and, according to my own experience with ML350 servers, valid: non-ECC memory is not supported.

ECC DDR-SDRAM modules have a 72-bit width, usually with 9 chips per side. In comparison, non-ECC modules only have a 64-bit width, with 8 chips per side. They are definitely different and, although you may be able to use ECC memory in non-ECC slots, the opposite is not generally possible.

Comment: Silly to worry about this on an 8 year-old server with limited RAM capacity anyway...

Comment: @ewwhite: having worked in environments with limited funds for hardware, I can always appreciate the value of a "free" hardware upgrade, much like the one the OP was hoping for...

Comment: Aye. Free upgrades should be fine for well backuppped TESTING/DEV servers. Vms might also be fine but sometimes you need to test with hardware (e.g. with PCI/PCIe/otherHWinputDevices). Having writtena ll that, for almost all other cases @ewwhite is right.